# Find missing dates from multi table query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm looking to write a query that can count missing entries from a table of dates based on skills that a resource has to forecast availability of resource for booking.  I'm not sure if it can be done and I'm certainly struggling with the logic!!

Tables

Dates

```
ID     dateFrom        StaffID
1       01-06-2014         1
2       02-06-2014         1
3       03-06-2014         1
4       04-06-2014         1
5       05-06-2014         1
6       01-06-2014         2
7       03-06-2014         2
8       04-06-2014         2
9       05-06-2014         2
10      06-06-2014         2
```

(Free dates on the 6th for staffID 1 and 2nd for staffID 2)

Staff

```
StaffID    Name
  1        John
  2        Paul
```

Skills

```
ID     StaffID  SkillID
1        1        1
2        1        2
3        1        3
4        2        2
5        2        3
6        2        4
```

So I want to write a query that says in June, for each of the skills there is X no of days available to book.  Is this even possible? looking for records that don't exist to join with a staff table?

I've put together a calendar table that can identify days without bookings but I'm struggling from there on to be honest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Steve

EDIT: DB is SQL 2005.

Expected output (if possible)

```
SkillID    Number of days available

  1              20
  2              22
  3              14
```

etc

Comment: Add what database you are working on and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a calendar table with all possible dates (booked or not)

```
select count(distinct ad.calendarDate), s.SkillID
from all_dates ad
cross join skills s
where not exists (
    select 1 from
    dates where dateFrom = ad.calendarDate
    and StaffID = s.StaffID
)
group by s.SkillID
```

Comment: How can I select a specific month for this query?  There is a large amount of data to trawl through.  I'm guessing it's adding the dates to the outer where clause?

Comment: @SteveMcCall correct, you can add the following to the outer `where` clause: `and ad.calendarDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'`

Comment: Ok, this seems to be producing a count of days grouped by skillID code but doesn't seem to be reducing the count where a day is booked (30 is shown as a count for every skill)  Any idea where Im' going wrong?

Comment: @SteveMcCall hard to tell w/o having access to the data you're running the query against. Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Looks like it's working fine in the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72d82/2  - can't understand the problem in my DB.  The only difference is that  the booked dates have times appended to them (2014-06-01 09:00 etc)

Comment: @SteveMcCall try removing the times in your subquery i.e `where convert(date,dateFrom) = cal.dt`

Comment: Yeah I've tried that and get the same result.  It must be something to do with the data as the example fiddle works fine.  I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, your query will be some thing like:

```
Select sum(temp.nbrDate), temp.SkillID from
  (Select s.SkillID, count (d.ID) as nbrDate from Skills s, Dates d
   where s.StaffID = d.StaffID
  Group by SkillID) temp
group by SkillID
```

If you want to add a date range, add this in your where close:

```
and d.DateForm between '01-06-2014' and '30-06-2014'
```